# Pages that were liked by my page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In Facebook if I am an admin of a page I can select to use the site "as page" under Account -> Use Facebook as Page. When doing so I "liked" some other pages.

My question: is there a way to get list of pages that were liked by my page (not my account). Is there a way to do it via Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, posting it here in case someone else needs it.

FQL:

```
select name,page_id from page where page_id in (select target_id from connection where source_id=MY_PAGE_ID and target_type="Page")
```

the request must be authenticated, so here is the whole request:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&query=select name,page_id from page where page_id in (select target_id from connection where source_id=MY_PAGE_ID and target_type="Page")
```